# Is it possible to have a dynamic storage path with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, carrierwave

I am starting with [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) for file uploads and have been  quite happy with it so far. My files are stored  on amazon s3 which was fairly easy and it works reliably.

Now I have a model named `pictures` and an uploader name `MainUploader`. I need a special dynamic path to save those files to when uploaded.

I am also using devise and I have the `current_user` I can access from my views and controller but not from the carrierwave uploader. I need the path of the file to be something like

`uploads/#{current_user.location}/#{current_user.first_name}/images`

but I cannot access the current_user from the uploader and haven't seen any alternatives. Is this type of dynamic path possible with carrierwave (without re-writing large amounts of this gem)?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case anyone else wondered here from a google search or something.

What I ended up doing was creating a belongs_to relationship on my model (`pictures`) to the User model. Then from carrierwave uploader I can do `model.user.first_name` which is the equivalent of `picture.user.first_name`. So I can put that model.user in my path and access any user attribute in that way. Hope this helps someone else.

Something like:

```
def store_dir
    "#{model.user.first_name}/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.title}"
end
```

ps
Note I also used `model.title` that is because I want the picture.title to be in the path as well. Not best practice though. If you do this make sure you parse model.title in production so it gives you a valid folder name/url.