# Is there a way to rename/override a file in CarrierWave to the username of the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have an avatar for each user, and the username is always going to be unique. This is why I wanted to rename the image to reflect the username of the person uploading said picture to make for easier fetching and solve any problems with image names clashing.

However, I'm having problems accessing the username of the person in my `app/uploader/avatar_uploader.rb` file. I had something along the lines of this.

```
def filename
    if original_filename
      @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
      "#{@user.username}.#{file.extension}"
    end
  end
```

I'm getting errors here that the params doesn't exist, and without that, the method username does not exist.

Overriding it to something such as `"foo.jpg"` does work and the file is successfully uploading, I'm just wondering how to access the username of the user uploading the file.

Answer (score 0):

`params[:id]` is `nil` unless you pass it with the request or embed in the route. But I don't recommend this way, because a user can change it to pass any `id`.

You should get the user who`s uploading the file from the session, for example using devise

`@user = current_user`

or if you have stored `user_id` in session:

`@user = User.find(session[:user_id])`

**EDIT**

The above code works only in controllers, that is, you need to get the user in the controller and pass to your uploader method:

`def filename(user)`

Comment: Okay, this makes sense, but where am I passing in the user at? Should the `filename(user)` get the current user?

Comment: I see, your question the specific to CarrierWave. Maybe this link is helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8470803/243797 (make a relation between the uploader's model and user, them use `model.user`)